# How to filter out current user from EntityType? (Symfony Forms)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have created a form `ConversationFormType` in which I want to get all the friends of that that user in an multiple choice select (EntityType).

The issue is in the select generated including the current user as well as their friends. is there any way I can filter out the current user from the output?

Thanks in advance.

Form\ConversationFormType.php

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {       
            $builder
                ->add('name', TextType::class,[
                    'label'=>'Conversation title'
                ])
                ->add('Users', EntityType::class, [
                    'label' => 'invite a friend to this conversation',
                    'attr'=>['class'=>'form-control'],
                    'class' => Friendship::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'friend.fullName',
                    'multiple'=>true,
                ]);
        }
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Conversation::class,
    ]);
}
```

Entity\Friendship.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FriendshipRepository")
 */
class Friendship
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="friendships")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="friendsWithMe")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    public $friend;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $date;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $user): self
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFriend(): ?User
    {
        return $this->friend;
    }

    public function setFriend(?User $friend): self
    {
        $this->friend = $friend;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate(\DateTimeInterface $date): self
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Entity\Conversation.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ConversationRepository")
 */
class Conversation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="conversations")
     */
    private $Users;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Message", mappedBy="conversation")
     */
    private $Messages;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $slug;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Users = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->Messages = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|User[]
     */
    public function getUsers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->Users;
    }

    public function addUser(User $user): self
    {
        if (!$this->Users->contains($user)) {
            $this->Users[] = $user;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUser(User $user): self
    {
        if ($this->Users->contains($user)) {
            $this->Users->removeElement($user);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Message[]
     */
    public function getMessages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->Messages;
    }

    public function addMessage(Message $message): self
    {
        if (!$this->Messages->contains($message)) {
            $this->Messages[] = $message;
            $message->setConversation($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMessage(Message $message): self
    {
        if ($this->Messages->contains($message)) {
            $this->Messages->removeElement($message);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($message->getConversation() === $this) {
                $message->setConversation(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(?string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(string $slug): self
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Update**

added a query builder as suggested still getting the same results:

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user) { 
     return $er->createQueryBuilder('none')
     ->from(Friendship::class,'friendship')
     ->where('friendship.user != friendship.friend')
     ->andWhere('friendship.user != :user')
     ->setParameter('user', $user);
},
```

Comment: You should create a validator that avoid a user to add himself as a friend. You should create an integrity constraint on your database that throw an error when user has the sameid than friend.

Comment: Use a [custom query](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities) and exclude the current user. You can get it injecting the `Security` service in your type.

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant yes, if I remove the current users id from the the output of friends then the user wouldn't be able to add themselves as a friend. But I'm trying to understand why the current user was included at all.

Comment: Doesn't that query return the friends of all users but mine? Shouldn't it be `'friendship.user' = :user`?

Comment: @msg Thanks but, that returns friends and the current user.

Answer (score 2):

The most generic way how to do it in Symfony 5 for me was:

Define default `current_id` value for my custom key in $options

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Conversation::class,
        'current_id' => 0
    ]);
}
```

Pass the current user id from controller, where you create your Form

```
$options['current_id'] = $user->getId();
$form = $this->createForm(ConversationFormType::class, $conversation, $options);
```

Use the options in query_builder

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) { 
     $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('f')
     ->from(Friendship::class,'friendship')
     ->where('friendship.user != friendship.friend');


    if(isset($options['current_id'])) {
        $qb->andWhere('friendship.user != :current_id')
         ->setParameter('current_id', $options['current_id']);

    }

    return $qb;
},
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, I was stuck because I didn't know how to pass options inside the promise. The **use** keyword was the key